# Slow queuing ajax request only in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have never had this issue before, however simply loading a page with an ajax request on it takes ages only in chrome, but is blazing fast in Firefox, Edge, and IE.

Below is a screenshot of the network timing in chrome:
[image]

If you look above, you see 5 major stalls with CDN'd scripts, however they are stalled for `~1.15s` each, but the resources above only took `~100ms` to get. Why would there be a HUGE gap in between loading resources?

Other resources are just stylesheets and scripts loaded locally and via CDN.

This is the timing screenshot in Edge:

[image]

At this point I have no idea what to do. Where do I go from here to "optimise" my page for Google Chrome?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Why would performance be horrible only in Chrome if my code caused bad performance?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I dont think you understand the situation. Chrome is delaying my resources from being loaded, however IE, Edge and firefox work perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find out why this happened in chrome? I'm facing a similar issue where my ASP.NET site is slow only in chrome, some of the ajax request are queuing after 1 minute in chrome where as works perfectly fine on IE, Edge and firefox, heck even older version of chrome (prior to version 58)

Comment: @sharath.g Not really, I think it was due to the massive amount of requests I was making. Still trying to find a solution. Try to decrease your requests (and if possible try HTTP/2)

Comment: @HunterMitchell are you able to find out why? I am also facing same issue

Comment: @HunterMitchell Do you have any update on this question?

Comment: @JohannesSetiabudi Sadly, I do not.It seems that the browser just didn't like that many calls at once.